# Computing Ehrhart's polynomial for a convex polytope

Tags: packages, computational-geometry, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Is there a *Mathematica* implementation for computing the [Ehrhart polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial) of a convex polytope which is specified either by its vertices or by a set of inequalities?

I am interested in knowing this because I understand that Ehrhart's polynomial for a polytope will determine the number of integer points inside this polytope.

Alternatively if someone knows of an existing method to count the number of integer points inside a convex polytope (described by its vertices or a set of inequalities), it would be equally helpful.

Comment: [This thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/how-to-plot-inequalities-taking-into-account-that-points-must-be-integers-and-no) looks helpful: it shows brute force ways to count lattice points within a polytope given by inequalities. They likely will fail in high dimensions because there will be too many points to inspect.

Comment: Thanks whuber. You're right, its not useful in higher dimensions. For my applications, I am having to deal with inequalities having n variables and 2n constraints. Here n ~ 20 to 30 . Also, I had seen that computing the volume of a general polytope is #P-Hard. I am suspecting that computing the coefficients of its Erhart-Polynomial too is hard. But still I am in search of algorithms. I found this software called LattE which seems to be reasonably fast for n=10 . However, I do not know how to invoke commands of this software from within a mathematica notebook or a script.

Comment: Have you seen [Barvinok's](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.1993.366830) [papers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02574364) already?